# ARR as reverse proxy for FTP server

Tags: proxy, ftp, iis, reverse-proxy

I would like your help in the following scenario: I currently use ARR in IIS to reverse proxy in HTTP and HTTPS sites, but now I need a reverse proxy for my FTP, and in research I found that ARR does not support FTP, that's right?

If the ARR really does not support, would they know some way, in Windows itself or not, that I achieve the same result of a reverse proxy for FTP? If ARR support, can you guide me in how to configure this?

Thank you.